# Latex - Headlines with Chapter (left = even page) and Section + Subsection (right = odd page)

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I would like to format my headlines like that:

**left page:** *left side:* Chapter x, *right side:* name of chapter

**rigt page:** *left side:* subsection, *right side:* name of subsubsection but only if there is an existing subsubsection.

With the `fancyhdr` package I could get so far that I got chapter and subsection as they are intended. But if I try to use `\renewcommand` `\subsectionmark` it overwrites the rightmark. Is there any simple way to point on the subsection title (like defining a variable or s.th. like that) and how can i define that it only appears if a subsection is existing (case structure perhaps)?

Here is the code up to now.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, ngerman, twocolumn, titlepage, intoc, BCOR=5mm]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection{~}{#1}}}


\rhead[subsectionname if subsection existing]{\leftmark}
\lhead[\rightmark]{\chaptername~\thechapter}
\lfoot[]{}
\cfoot[\thepage]{\thepage}
\rfoot[]{}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Wurst}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\section{Fleischwurst}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\subsection{Lyoner}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This is what I get:

[image: Headline Problem]

I hope my problem is understadable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think the same feature can be achieved without `fancyhdr` by using the features of the KOMA script bundle (see `scrpage2`)

Comment: As far as I have read the KOMA script description the problem remains the same. I can only refer to leftmark and rightmark. I dont get it how to get section and subsection into the same mark and get it there without the subsection overwriting the section.

Comment: Do you really mean the name of `subsubsection` on the right page (if present at all) or should it be `subsection` rather?

Comment: Oh im sorry, its subsection if present, not subsubsection. And I right now saw that I inverted the pages. Somehow I thought the even pages are on the right. But thats not the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the chapter/section/subsection etc. title is always a problem, as long it should be expandable, otherwise `\nameref{}` would do. I redefined the slightly the `\chapter` and `\subsection` commands to store the current title in a `\chaptertitle` or `\subsectiontitle` command, which is used then as input for `\rohead` etc. commands from `scrpage2` package.

Most of the direct setup of the page headers could be achieved with `fancyhdr` package as well, however, as the KOMA script manual states, `scrpage2` works better in conjunction with KOMA classes, but that's quite natural, as `scrpage2` is part of the KOMA bundle.

Fiddling around with `headmark`, `chaptermark` etc. is always tedious, in my point of view.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, ngerman, twocolumn, titlepage, intoc, BCOR=5mm]{scrbook}

%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}

%\fancyhf{}
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection{~}{#1}}}

%\rhead[subsectionname if subsection existing]{\leftmark}
%\lhead[\rightmark]{\chaptername~\thechapter}
%\lfoot[]{}
%\cfoot[\thepage]{\thepage}
%\rfoot[]{}


\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%% My additions
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{scrpage2}%

\newcommand{\headseplinecolor}{blue}%

\pagestyle{scrheadings}%

\newcommand{\subsectiontitle}{}%

\makeatletter
\let\LaTeXStandardsubsection\subsection
\newcommand{\unstarred@@subsection@@noopt}[1]{%
  \unstarred@@subsection@@opt[#1]{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\unstarred@@subsection@@opt}[2][]{%
  \renewcommand{\subsectiontitle}{#1}%
  \LaTeXStandardsubsection[#1]{#2}%
}%

\newcommand{\unstarredsubsection}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\unstarred@@subsection@@opt}{\unstarred@@subsection@@noopt}%
}%

\newcommand{\starredsubsection}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\subsectiontitle}{#1}%
\LaTeXStandardsubsection*{#1}%
}%

\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
\@ifstar{\starredsubsection}{\unstarredsubsection}%
}%
%%%%%

\newcommand{\sectiontitle}{}%


\let\LaTeXStandardsection\section
\newcommand{\unstarred@@section@@noopt}[1]{%
  \unstarred@@section@@opt[#1]{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\unstarred@@section@@opt}[2][]{%
  \renewcommand{\sectiontitle}{#1}%
  \LaTeXStandardsection[#1]{#2}%
}%

\newcommand{\unstarredsection}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\unstarred@@section@@opt}{\unstarred@@section@@noopt}%
}%

\newcommand{\starredsection}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\sectiontitle}{#1}%
  \LaTeXStandardsection*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}#1}%
}%

\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \@ifstar{\starredsection}{\unstarredsection}%
}%

\newcommand{\chaptertitle}{}%

\makeatletter
\let\LaTeXStandardchapter\chapter
\newcommand{\unstarred@@chapter@@noopt}[1]{%
  \unstarred@@chapter@@opt[#1]{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\unstarred@@chapter@@opt}[2][]{%
  \renewcommand{\chaptertitle}{#1}%
  \LaTeXStandardchapter[#1]{#2}%
}%

\newcommand{\unstarredchapter}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\unstarred@@chapter@@opt}{\unstarred@@chapter@@noopt}%
}%

\newcommand{\starredchapter}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\chaptertitle}{#1}%
\LaTeXStandardchapter*{#1}%
}%

\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
\@ifstar{\starredchapter}{\unstarredchapter}%
}%

\makeatother


\clearscrplain
\clearscrheadings
\lehead{\ifnumgreater{\number\value{section}}{0}{\sectiontitle}{}}%
\rehead{\ifnumgreater{\number\value{subsection}}{0}{\subsectiontitle}{}}%
\lohead{\chapapp~\thechapter}%
\rohead{\chaptertitle}%
\setheadsepline{2pt}[\color{\headseplinecolor}]

%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Wurst}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\section{Fleischwurst}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\subsection{Lyoner}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\section{Salami}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\subsection{Chorizo}
\lipsum
\lipsum



\end{document}
```

### recto page (right)

[image]

### verso page (left)

[image]

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what @@ does. I'll copy all that to a new file and go through it step by step to see what the recomands do. Alternatively, if you have ambitions to explain it to me, you could add some more comments. Sorry but I wrote my master thesis based on a template that was given by the university but I wanted to understand a bit more about LateX and what it's capable of. @your addons: Shouldn't you have added Schwarzwälder Schinken? xD

Comment: @Björn: Sorry, I forgot about that restriction: Just take @@ as special characters I use to distinguish more low-level commands from `user level` commands.

Comment: The basic problem is, that all of the commands like `\chapter` etc. do not store the title of the chapter etc. somewhere (why???? I don't know), therefore, it is necessary to redefine those commands. However, there are `\chapter[]{}`, `\chapter{}` and `\chapter*{}` commands (the same holds for `\section` etc.) and to keep LaTeX from complaining, all of those commands must be redefined.

Comment: Could the ID be "user:61135" this number? @Christian: That means you did redefine all commands even if you do not need them to avoid problems and \unstarred@@chapter@@noopt is for \chapter{} and so on?

Comment: @Björn: I am not sure about the number... The redefinition is to get access to the section etc. titles not available otherwise.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16613/discussion-on-answer-by-christian-hupfer-latex-headlines-with-chapter-odd-pag).

Comment: There are two things that happen now that I do not understand. The first thing is that i added to the code just `\cfoot{\pagemark}` but the page dosen't appear when a new chapter begins. The second thing is that my editor marks `\numberline` as unknown command. Could there be a package missing?

Comment: @Björn: `\numberline` is a inherent LaTeX command, it can't be unknown. I will look after the `page` stuff

Comment: @Björn: `\cfoot{\pagemark}` works as expected, however, chapter starting pages have no page numbers, of course, as their pagestyle is `plain`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I didn't see, that there is an option for `\cfoot` to apply on `plain` style. So `\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}` works properly. Meanwhile TeXstudio moreoften marks commands as unknown but there is no failure compiling the file so I think we can forget about that. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Björn: Well, I don't use TeXStudio etc. I compile the hard way ;-)